# how avoid freezing other threads when one thread locks a big map

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, stl, mutex

How to avoid freezing other threads which try to access the same map that is being locked by current thread? see below code:

```
           //pseudo code
           std::map<string, CSomeClass* > gBigMap;
           void AccessMapForWriting(string aString){
                 pthread_mutex_lock(&MapLock);

                 CSomeClass* obj = gBigMap[aString];
                 if (obj){
                       gBigMap.erase(aString);

                       delete obj;
                       obj = NULL;
                 }


                 pthread_mutex_unlock(&MapLock);
           }

           void AccessMapForReading(string aString){
                 pthread_mutex_lock(&MapLock);
                 CSomeClass* obj = gBigMap[aString];

                 //below code consumes much time
                 //sometimes it even sleeps for milliseconds
                 if (obj){
                     obj->TimeConsumingOperation();
                 }

                 pthread_mutex_unlock(&MapLock);
           }

           //other threads will also call 
           //the same function -- AccessMap
           void *OtherThreadFunc(void *){
                 //call AccessMap here
           }
```

Comment: You can take a look at pthread_mutex_trylock: http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_trylock

Comment: all the threads will call the same function -- AccessMap

Comment: If you are only ever locking to read the map, you don't need the lock, though I suspect I might be missing something.

Comment: @doctorlove Some thread might access the map to remove some elements from it, but this happens rarely, but accessing the map for reading happend frequently.

Comment: @doctorlove bear in mind, "reading" a map via `operator[]` can also mean writing.

Comment: @juanchopanza Of course - to make sure you are just reading you'd have to use something other than [], I just asked at a more conceptual level, IYSWIM

Comment: @juanchopanza I plan to try the rwlock until I see your comments. what do you think about using rwlock?

Comment: The `rwlock` is fine as long as you are sure you are not writing. `operator[]` introduces an element into the map if one with the given key is not present, which is why I said it can also write. You can use the `at()` method instead. In general, you should only be using `const` medhods in the reading threads.

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks for pointing out this important message about operator[], that's so helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a read write lock instead, `pthread_rwlock_t`
There are some details [here](http://www.cognitus.net/html/howto/pthreadSemiFAQ_10.html)
It says

> "Using a normal mutex, when a thread obtains the mutex all other
>   threads are forced to block until that mutex is released by the owner.
>
> What about the situation where the vast majority of threads are simply
>   reading the data? If this is the case then we should not care if there
>   is 1 or up to N readers in the critical section at the same time. In
>   fact the only time we would normally care about exclusive ownership is
>   when a writer needs access to the code section."

Comment: Good luck - make sure you watch out for  juanchopanza's comment and that you are *reading* when you read, since [] will insert key/values if they don't exist

Answer (score 0):

You have a `std::string` as a key. Can you break down that key in a short suffix (possibly just a single letter) and a remainder? Because in that case, you might implement this datastructure as 255 maps with 255 locks. That of course means that most of the time, there's no lock contention because the suffix differs, and therefore the lock.

Comment: I am afraid not. Actually here the string is used to store the username and there might be thousands of users online which means there might be thousands of elements in this map.

Comment: @StevePeng: That's in fact quite good. You'd break it down into a hundred or so users per map by just using the first letter of their name to choose a map and lock. So `pthread_mutex_lock(&MapLock[aString[0]);` and `CSomeClass* obj = gBigMap[aString[0]][aString];`. Users Joe and Fred will not have lock contention, because Joe uses the J lock and Fred uses the F lock.

Comment: Thanks MSalters, I will try this way and choose a better one comparing with method of using pthread_rwlock_t.